# Inhomogeneous Legendre recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, legendre-polynomials

How can I find the particular solution to following recurrence relation for $F_n(x,r)$?:

$$nF_n +(2n-1)xrF_{n-1}+(n-1)r^2F_{n-2}=1$$
Withe initial values $F_0=0, F_1=1$.

The corresponding homogeneous equation is the same as the recurrence relation for the Legendre Polynomials, except with the $r$ prefactors. The homogeneous solution is $(-r)^n W_{n-1}(x)$, where 
$$W_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{P_{n-k}P_{k-1}}{k};\qquad W_{-1}=0$$

and $P_n$ are the Legendre polynomials. The full solution is a homogeneous solution plus a particular solution; I don't know if this helps. The first few orders don't seem to have an obvious pattern...

Any ideas or hints or references are much appreciated.

(This problem came across in research)

Comment: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/frameindex.htm If you want try looking here, section 22 "Orthogonal polynomials". You might find your recurrence relation in the tables

Comment: Thanks - I've looked there already though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define the generating function of the sequence in question. We have:
\begin{equation}
F(y) := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty F_n y^n
\end{equation}
Now, it is not hard to see that this function satisfies the following differential equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d F(y)}{d y} + \frac{x r+ r^2 y}{1+2 x r y+r^2 y^2} F(y) = \left(\frac{y}{1-y}+F_1+F_0 x r\right) \frac{1}{1+2 x r y+r^2 y^2}
\end{eqnarray}
subject to $F(0)=F_0$ and $F^{'}(0)=F_1$. Define $b:=r/\sqrt{1+r^2+2 r x}$.

Then the solution to the differential equation reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&F(y)= \frac{1}{r \sqrt{1+2 r x y+r^2 y^2}} \left[\right.\\
&&\left. F_0 r+\right.\\
&&\left.(F_0 r x+F_1-1)\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2 y^2+2 r x y+1}+r y+x}{x+1}\right)+\right.\\
&&\left.b \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2+2 r x+1} \sqrt{r^2 y^2+2 r x y+1}+r^2 y+r x (y+1)+1}{(1-y) \left(\sqrt{r^2+2 r x+1}+r x+1\right)}\right)\right.\\
&&\left.\right]
\end{eqnarray}
Now all we need to do is to invert the Z-transform, meaning compute:
\begin{equation}
F_n(x,r) = \frac{1}{n!} \left. \frac{d^n F(y)}{d y^n} \right|_{y=0}
\end{equation}
for $n=0,1,\cdots$.

Out of the three terms in square brackets the top one is proportional to the $n$th Legendre polynomial in $x$ . The two remaining terms yield something else though.